# R - extract values from strings

Tags: r, string

I'm working with some data that has strings like these:

1) `C: 0.664 (3327)T: 0.336 (1681)`

2) `C|C: 0.462 (1158)C|T: 0.404 (1011)T|T: 0.134 (335)`

I'm interested in extracting just the letters and the numbers within the parenthesis to get data frames like these:

1)

```
L1   N1 L2   N2
 C 3327  T 1681
```

2)

```
L1   N1 L2   N2 L3  N3
CC 1158 CT 1011 TT 335
```

Is there any function/package or efficient way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```
x = c(
  "C: 0.664 (3327)T: 0.336 (1681)", 
  "C|C: 0.462 (1158)C|T: 0.404 (1011)T|T: 0.134 (335)"
)
```

Select parts

```
s = strsplit(x, "\\)|(:.*?\\()")

# [[1]]
# [1] "C"    "3327" "T"    "1681"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "C|C"  "1158" "C|T"  "1011" "T|T"  "335"
```

The regex matches two things: `\\)` or `:.*?\\(`. In the second:

- `.` matches any character
- `*` quantifies the match as "any character any number of times"
- `?` tells  the quantifier to be "non-greedy" so it stops at `\\(`, even though that also matches `.`.

---

From there, it's pretty straightforward to perform your remaining formatting tasks:

```
Map(function(r, n) 
    setNames( gsub("\\|", "", r), paste0(c("L","N"), rep(seq(n), each=2)) ),
  s, 
  lengths(s)/2
)

# [[1]]
#     L1     N1     L2     N2 
#    "C" "3327"    "T" "1681" 
# 
# [[2]]
#     L1     N1     L2     N2     L3     N3 
#   "CC" "1158"   "CT" "1011"   "TT"  "335"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Frank ! It works brilliantly. I just would like to understand the regexp that you're using, i.e. "\\)|(:.*?\\()". I can see that you're escaping the parenthesis, but cannot get the whole meaning. If possible, can you clarify this? Thanks again!

Comment: @jroberayalas Cool. I've added an explanation. I only learned of the `*?` recently, seeing it on this site. I couldn't find clear documentation of it to point to, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `stri_extract_all` from `library(stringi)` after removing the `|` with `gsub`.  We use lookahead (`(?=:)`) and match one or more characters that are not `)` or we match one or more character that are not `)` (`[^)]+`) followed by the lookbehind (`(?<=\\()`).

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(gsub('\\|', '', x), '[^)]+(?=:)|(?<=\\()[^)]+')
#[[1]]
#[1] "C"    "3327" "T"    "1681"

#[[2]]
#[1] "CC"   "1158" "CT"   "1011" "TT"   "335"
```

---

We could also use two `gsub` and then convert the output to a `data.frame`.  The `class` of the numeric and character elements are differentiated using this method.

```
res <- read.table(text=gsub('\\:[^(]+|[()]', ' ',
          gsub('[|]', '', x)),
         sep='', header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='', fill=TRUE)
#  V1   V2 V3   V4   V5  V6
#1  C 3327  T 1681 <NA>  NA
#2 CC 1158 CT 1011   TT 335


str(res)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "C" "CC"
# $ V2: int  3327 1158
# $ V3: chr  "T" "CT"
# $ V4: int  1681 1011
# $ V5: chr  NA "TT"
# $ V6: int  NA 335
```

NOTE: We can change the column names using `?colnames`